# Session Variables not being seen/used

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page that displays a gridview of questions waiting on review with 10 questions shown per page. If a question is selected it is opened in a new page where the reviewer can either submit a review or cancel and return to the list of questions needing review.

Currently this works fine, but have a request from the reviewers so that if they are on page 4 of the gridview when they go to a question, they get returned to page 4 if they hit cancel and return to the list of questions (currently they are returned to page 1).

So I am setting a couple session variables to capture the question selected and to capture the pageindex of the gridview control for future use. Trying to use the session variable for the questionId on the page load of the detail page, but it is not being passed. On returning to the Review List page the pageindex that is being set on the gridview is always 0, not the session variable.

Updated Gridview control (note two  controls, one hyperlink(which should go away once the other linkbutton control works):

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Caption="Questions Awaiting Review" AllowSorting="True" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
CaptionAlign="Top" EmptyDataText="No Questions Pending Review." PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" PagerStyle-Font-Size="Large" DataKeyNames="QuestionID"
AutoGenerateColumns="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#cccccc">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="QuestionID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="KeyObjective" HeaderText="Key Objective" ItemStyle-Width="250" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SubmitDate" HeaderText="Submitted Date" ItemStyle-Width="60" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="Details" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Review/ReviewDetail.aspx?Id=" + Eval("QuestionID") +"&PageIndex=" + GridView1.PageIndex %>'>View Question</asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Details2" runat="server" Text="Session" OnClick="Session_OnClick"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

OnClick Event for the second button:

```
protected void Session_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["PageIndex"] = GridView1.PageIndex;
        Session["QuestionId"] = GridView1.SelectedDataKey;
        Response.Redirect("~/Review/ReviewDetail.aspx", false;

    }
```

Connection string on the detail page which is now not getting a value for the parameter "QuestionID";    ):

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("QuestionDetail", Conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt));

            command.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = Convert.ToInt64(Session["QuestionId"]);
            Conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

PageLoad and gridview binding on the ReviewList page that should be using session variable to set page of grid control, but is always going to default of page 0:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
                bindGridView();
        }
        else
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["PageIndex"]) !=0)
            {
                GridView1.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["PageIndex"]);
                bindGridView();
            }
        }
    }
   private void bindGridView()
   {
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
            string selectSQL = String.Format("Select QuestionID, KeyObjective, SubmitDate from Questions where Author <> '{0}' and QuestionID not in(Select QuestionID from Review where Reviewer = '{0}')", User.Identity.Name);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(ds, "Review");

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();

   }
```

Comment: You should open developer console in your browser and watch what location is really in response header of your redirect.. I'm sure it will help you.

Comment: when I run debugger in firefox all that I get back when I click that button is: __doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl02$Details2','')     No idea what that should be telling me.

Comment: When you look to response headers of your redirect, you will see what url are you redirected to and probably will see what's the problem with that "Id" parameter in querystring (wrong format, empty..). Don't look at javascript console, you have to look to network tab (that's how its called in chrome, I don't use FF) and see how rosponse looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error probably means that `Request["Id"]` is empty or does not exists. Always check if QueryStrings exist and do the conversions of user inputs that are likely to fail inside a try-catch block.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long QuestionID = -1;

        //check if the Id QueryString exists
        if (Request.QueryString["Id"] != null)
        {
            //try to convert to int64
            try
            {
                QuestionID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["Id"]);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        //if valid QuestionID
        if (QuestionID >= 0)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("QuestionDetail", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add("@QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = QuestionID;

                //try to execute the stored procedure
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //handle sql error
                    Literal1.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And why do you do a PostBack on the first button? That is not needed just to redirect to a different url. Change it to:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Review/ReviewDetail.aspx?Id=" + Eval("QuestionID") %>'>View Question</asp:HyperLink>
```

Or with the Page Index also in the QueryString:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Review/ReviewDetail.aspx?Id=" + Eval("QuestionID") + "&Page=" + GridView2.PageIndex %>'>View Question</asp:HyperLink>
```

**UPDATE**

If you really want to do a PostBack to set the Sessions you can use the OnRowCommand:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' runat="server" CommandName="viewQuestion">View Question</asp:LinkButton>
```

CS

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "viewQuestion")
        {
            Session["PageIndex"] = GridView1.PageIndex;
            Session["QuestionId"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/Review/ReviewDetail.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(Session["QuestionId"]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the changing to hyperlink and adding pageindex to the line helped to save the pageindex when moving to detail record. Now I'm having an issue with the pageindex not being picked up when returning to the list page. Maybe another question if I can't sort it out.

Comment: Actually did not understand some of this. Changing the first button to Hyperlink works,,, but it worked before. I'm still no closer to getting the session variable that I am setting to work as the second button does not work. Since I cannot undo my acceptance of answer, guess I'll have to resubmit the question again :(

Comment: updated question with new version,,, non of the session variables seem to be picked up and used anywhere??

Comment: Updated my answer. My example has now a link in the GridView that does a postback that does sends the questionID.

Comment: Input the changes, all the button does is reload the ReviewList page.

Comment: added OnRowCommandEvent="GridView1_RowCommand" to the gridview, still does nothing but reload the current page?

Comment: changed to OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" and now the detail page opens correctly, but not getting the gridview to go to correct pageindex on return.

Comment: thanks for all your help. Was able to sort out the remaining issues and page/s look to be performing correctly now.